# SQL change a value on export

Tags: sql

I'm pulling students from my database and their status=0 the system I'm exporting to has to have their status=1. I can get the query to pull the status but I don't know how to change it to 1 for the export to the other system?

Thanks in advance!

```
select STUDENTS.FIRST_NAME as "firstname",
    STUDENTS.LAST_NAME as "lastname",
    STUDENTS.STUDENT_NUMBER as "idNumber",
    STUDENTS.ENROLL_STATUS as "status",
    STUDENTS.SCHOOLID as "school",
    STUDENTS.CLASSOF as "gradyear",
    U_DEF_EXT_STUDENTS.GSUITEEMAILADDRESS as "email" 
 from U_DEF_EXT_STUDENTS U_DEF_EXT_STUDENTS,
    STUDENTS STUDENTS 
 where U_DEF_EXT_STUDENTS.STUDENTSDCID=STUDENTS.DCID
        and STUDENTS.SCHOOLID =1992
        and STUDENTS.ENROLL_STATUS =0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign 1 to the status

```
SELECT STUDENTS.FIRST_NAME as "firstname",
       STUDENTS.LAST_NAME as "lastname",
       STUDENTS.STUDENT_NUMBER as "idNumber",
       1 as "status", -- assign 1 to status
       STUDENTS.SCHOOLID as "school",
       STUDENTS.CLASSOF as "gradyear",
       U_DEF_EXT_STUDENTS.GSUITEEMAILADDRESS as "email" 
  FROM U_DEF_EXT_STUDENTS U_DEF_EXT_STUDENTS
 INNER JOIN STUDENTS STUDENTS 
    ON U_DEF_EXT_STUDENTS.STUDENTSDCID = STUDENTS.DCID
 WHERE STUDENTS.SCHOOLID = 1992
   AND STUDENTS.ENROLL_STATUS = 0
```